# Azure storage blob container keeps increasing in size, though it only has one file

Tags: azure

I have created a simple Storage account on Azure portal. And I backup **one** file on it nightly from my server.

The file is about 300 MBs in size.

But each time I go to Azure storage browser (currently in preview) I see that the total size is increased.

I don't keep separate files. I just override the same file each night. I expect it to show me 300 MBs, but it keeps growing (more than 8GBs now).

How can I fix this? What configuration should I change?

Comment: Do you create snapshots?

Comment: I don't. But does it automatically? How can I turn it off?